# avplayer flushes buffer after going foreground

Tags: swift, background, buffer, avplayer, playback

I have a custom video player based on Avplayer + detecting of video buffer using progress bar.

The problem is buffer flushes (cleans, start buffering again) after collapsing for 5 sec, just need to pause video, collapse app, swipe to left-right on home screen - open app again - start video, buffering starts from scratch + receiving "isPlaybackBufferEmpty" observer fire.

The code I use for player:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet var containerPlayer: PlayerView!
    
@objc var player = AVPlayer()
        
let toPass = "https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8"
        
private var bufferObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
private var playerItemBufferEmptyObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
private var playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
            
            
  containerPlayer.player = self.player
  containerPlayer.playerLayer.player = self.player
            
  startPlayer()
}
    
func startPlayer() {
   if let videoURL = URL(string: self.toPass) {
      let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
                
      let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                
      self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
      self.player.currentItem?.preferredPeakBitRate = 0
                
      self.player.currentItem?.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 10
    
      self.player.play()
                
      playerItemBufferEmptyObserver = item.observe(\.isPlaybackBufferEmpty, options: [.old, .new]) { [weak self] (playerItem, _) in
          if playerItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty {
               print("playerItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty")
          }
      }
    
      playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver = item.observe(\.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (playerItem, _) in
          if playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
             print("playerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp")
          }
       }
    
       bufferObserver = item.observe(\.loadedTimeRanges, options:  [.new], changeHandler: { (playerItem, change) in
            if let timeRange = playerItem.loadedTimeRanges.first?.timeRangeValue {
                        let startSeconds = timeRange.start.seconds
                        let durationSeconds = timeRange.duration.seconds
                        let bufferEnd = startSeconds + durationSeconds
    
                        let positionTimeElapsed: Float64 = Float64(bufferEnd) / playerItem.asset.duration.seconds
                        self.progressBar.progress = Float(positionTimeElapsed)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Did anybody faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Apple Engineer using DTS:

> AVPlayer does not offer you control over its internal buffering after
> the player is paused and the app goes into the background. While on
> the foreground, you can adjust the preferredForwardBufferDuration
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1643630-preferredforwardbufferduration,
> which your sample code already implements.
>
> There is no mechanism for you to control AVPlayer’s buffering when
> your app goes into the background, as mentioned above. One option is
> to enable the “Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture” [2] background
> mode and keep playing back when the app goes into the background.
> Persisting an HLS stream can also be done in such a way that the
> download continues in the background, even if your app is not playing
> back the stream.
>
> To avoid delays when resuming playback after your app comes again to
> the foreground, your app can persist the HLS stream. Using
> AVFoundation to Play and Persist HTTP Live Streams
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams is a piece of sample code that exemplifies this.